# How do I resolve dependencies using an object of an associated type using AutoFac?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, dependency-management

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to create a 1:1 mapping between objects in a container using AutoFac. I am getting resolution errors and the documentation is too terse with not enough examples.

Here's the rule I would like to use to resolve my dependencies:
An IHouse object can only be constructed using an IDoor parameter of a specific concrete type, creating a 1:1 mapping between IHouse and IDoor types.

As am example, using the code below, if I resolve the container using a MonkeyDoor, it should give me back a fully constructed MonkeyHouse and only a MonkeyHouse object.

```
[TestClass]
public class HousingDeveloperTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // Load them from an assembly or disc. We are interested in IHouse and IDoor types
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Get all the houses
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith(nameof(House))).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        // get all the doors
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith(nameof(Door))).AsImplementedInterfaces(); 

        var container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {

            var house = container.Resolve<IDoor>(new TypedParameter(typeof(MonkeyDoor), new MonkeyDoor()));
        }
    }
}


public interface IDoor
{
    void Open();
}

public abstract class Door : IDoor
{
    public void Open()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Opening {GetType().ToString()}.");
    }
}

// Only works with Victorian homes
public class VictorianDoor : Door
{
}

// Only works with Craftsman homes
public class CraftsmanDoor : Door
{
}

// Only works with monkey homes
public class MonkeyDoor : Door
{
}

public interface IHouse
{
    void OpenHouse();
}

public abstract class House : IHouse
{
    public IDoor Door;

    protected House(IDoor door)
    {
        Door = door;
        Trace.WriteLine($"Building this {this.GetType()} with {door.GetType()} door.");
    }

    public void OpenHouse()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"We're having an open house on this wonderful {this.GetType().ToString()}.");
        Door.Open();
    }
}

// Doors must match the homes. (i.e. No monkey doors on a Victorian or Craftsman home.)
public class VictorianHouse : House
{
    public VictorianHouse(VictorianDoor door) : base(door)
    {
    }
}

public class CraftsmanHouse : House
{
    public CraftsmanHouse(CraftsmanDoor door) : base(door)
    {
    }
}

public class MonkeyHouse : House
{
    public MonkeyHouse(MonkeyDoor door) : base(door)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried registering AsSelf as well as AsImplementedInterfaces?

Comment: No I haven't.  The docs are a bit confusing and makes my head hurt.

Comment: I wrote most of the docs so if you file an issue on the autofac/Documentation repo explaining what was unclear we can fix it. In the meantime, try AsSelf.

Comment: My problem is I don't know  resolve a VictorianHouse object from VictorianDoor object without referring to the concrete types.  I plan on keeping a list of instantiated doors registered from an assembly and go through the list and resolve houses from them.  Those doors and homes are plugins.  Essentially, I trying to find out how to wire them up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hope it makes sense.  In other words, here is a door, find the house it belongs to based on its type.